# getBy404 vs get404

Tags: haskell, yesod, persist

I'm trying to build a rest service using the Yesod web framework. I can get entries by Id but I cannot get them by unique key. It's because the types signature of getBy404 is different to get404. getBy404 returns the value wrapped in a Entity and get404 returns the pure value.

```
module Handler.MusicaUser where
import Import

getMusicaUserR :: MusicaUserId -> Handler Value
getMusicaUserR pid = do
post <- runDB $ get404 pid

    return $ object ["user" .= (Entity pid post)]

putMusicaUserR :: MusicaUserId -> Handler Value
putMusicaUserR pid = do
    post <- requireJsonBody :: Handler MusicaUser

    runDB $ replace pid post

    sendResponseStatus status200 ("UPDATED" :: Text)

deleteMusicaUserR :: MusicaUserId -> Handler Value
deleteMusicaUserR pid = do
    runDB $ delete pid

    sendResponseStatus status200 ("DELETED" :: Text)
```

I have tried modifying my code using this example

[Why does this code work with Yesod.Persist's get404 but not getBy404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793336/why-does-this-code-work-with-yesod-persists-get404-but-not-getby404)

Thank. I appreciate your help.

EDIT

I think I'm getting closer

```
getMusicaUserR :: Int64 -> Handler Value
getMusicaUserR facebookId = do
   user <- runDB $ getBy404 (UniqueFacebookId facebookId)
   return $ object ["user" .= (user)]
```

The error I get now is

```
Application.hs:41:1:
    Couldn't match type ‘Int64’ with ‘Key MusicaUser’
    Expected type: MusicaUserId
      Actual type: Int64
    In the first argument of ‘MusicaUserR’, namely ‘dyn_al6K’
    In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘MusicaUserR dyn_al6K’
```

Is Int64 the correct type for my function. The reason I used it is because that is how facebookId is defined in my model. I have also tried using UniqueFacebookId.

To fix the above error I needed to change my routes definitions to

/users/#Int64 instead of /users/MusicaUserId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at [the definition of Entity](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.1.0/docs/Database-Persist-Store.html#t%3AEntity), you can see that it is just a container for an entity and it's key. You can use the two functions `entityKey` and `entityVal` to extract the key and the value from the return value of `getBy404`.

Comment: Thank you very much @madjar. I think I've gotten close. Still not quite there.

Comment: The error you added with your edit doesn't look like a problem with the function. Maybe there's a problem with your route definition: it should be of the form `/something/#Int64`, not `/something/#MusicaUserId`, since the route functions takes an Int64.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! Incredible that routes are type safe. Would it be a good idea to create a new type using Int64 to make a facebookId type?

Comment: A type alias (`type FacebookId = Int64`) could indeed increase the readability, but I feel more than that would be overkill.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that. What file would be the best place to put that definition in? I've taken 2 Haskell courses but this is my first time actually building something that isn't a data structure or numerical problem using Haskell. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It very much depends on how your application is structured. I'd put it near the routes definitions so that the `/something/#FacebookId` makes immediate sense.